# Masonry. Change container id name

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-float

guys!

I need some help in Masonry layout (masonry.desandro.com). This library uses container with name "container". But in my site (this is OpenCart based e-shope) id="container" already exist. Is it possible to change hard-coded container's name to another? Or may be you advice  me another (lightweight is better) library.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`id="container"` is used just for example, you could use your own selector, like

```
var $container = $('#some_id'); //use your own id as selector
$container.masonry({
      columnWidth: 200,
     itemSelector: '.item'
});
```